# Update rails app to ruby 2.0.0 bundler error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I started a Heroku Rails app using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.0.1.

I decided soon after to update my ruby version to 2.0.0 as this apparently works better with Rails 4.0.1. So, I installed the ruby2.0 package using apt-get and other associated packages, then I set ruby 2.0.0 as the default using `sudo ruby-switch --set ruby2.0`, finally I updated the Gemfile in my app, changing the line `ruby '1.9.3'` to `ruby '2.0.0'` Now, when I run `bundle install` I am presented with this error, and I don't know why...

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

Following [this heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) didn't seem to help... I set the path to what is shown there and it didn't seem change anything. Maybe I am being stupid and there is something in that path that I need to replace something with information specific to my machine? I feel like the part where I set `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin` should have some specific info, like changing "vendor" to something but I don't know what... I'm not totally familiar with this stuff yet, this is my first time using heroku and ruby.

EDIT: I forgot to mention (in case it is important) I am running Xubuntu 13.10.

Comment: What does `ruby --version` report in the same terminal you run `bundle install` from? Perhaps you have set the system default ruby, but not your current version?

Comment: do you get this error when pushing to heroku? i think you are mixing stuff here!

Comment: calling `ruby --version` tells me it is 2.0.0. Pushing to heroku seems to go smoothly, though. I think it's actually working... not sure what I should expect to see with a new rails app... http://citizens-parliament.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have fixed the issue. I was somehow running the bundle command which was installed for ruby 1.9.3... so when it compared the gemfile definition with the version it was running on they mismatched. Re-rerunning `sudo gem install bundler` has sorted it out.